# Boto3 SNS inconsistent behavior publishing text message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a function that sends off a text message when run:

```
def txtUserValidationCode(countryCode, phoneNum, message):
    sns = boto3.client('sns')
    try:
        logger.info("Trying to send text")
        sns.publish(
            PhoneNumber="+" + countryCode + phoneNum,
            Message=message
        )
    except:
        logger.info("Text message failed")
    else:
        logger.info("Text message successful")
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it times out, even when the input parameters are exactly the same. Is there a throttle on how many texts you can send with boto3 SNS? I just tried to hard code the phone number and message in to test whether it was my inputs throwing the publish method off, however it still did not work.

Even more confusing is the fact that it is not throwing an error, just a timeout.

More confusing is the fact when I copy and paste the same code into another function, it works fine.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? I read through SNS docs and did not find anything that could explain this. I am thinking maybe I need to request a quota increase?

btw: lambda has admin permissions

**UPDATE**
Function just succeeded, changed nothing, just tested it again after 15 minutes. Would really like to know what accounts for the timeout. Should I increase the timeout for my lambda? I also changed the default type of text message to transactional as I see they get higher priority? Perhaps this is why? Any answers help

Comment: No, you should not need to request a quota increase, as long as you do not get actual errors. Do you actually get the first log statement printed even though the following message publishing times out? in what way does it timeout? Does the lambda function itself time out or the publishing call?

Comment: The "trying to send text" log statement prints out, and then the full function times out, however this is the final function call in the entire lambda function, so it gets through everything else according to my logging, and then when it hits the text message function it does not get through

Comment: Increase the lambda timeout to 15 minutes and see what the logs say then, if the lambda itself still times out or if you get a proper response / error from sns.

Comment: Will try, function just succeeded, do not know why. Very weird

Comment: The symptoms suggest a connectivity issue. You might want to enhance the Lambda function to test connectivity before invoking SNS APIs, e.g. curl/ping Google or some other available service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the SNS console and changed my default message to transactional, which gives it higher precedence in AWS queue. So far, that has worked without fail.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an AWS Lambda function that is associated with multiple subnets, and some of those subnets are public and some are private.

The preference would be to use an AWS Lambda function that is *not* associated with a VPC. This will provide direct access to the Internet and, therefore, to Amazon SNS.

However, if the AWS Lambda function is associated with a VPC, ensure that:

- The Lambda function is only associated with **private subnets**
- There is a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in a public subnet

Comment: Lambda is in private vpc and connecting with internet through the NAT gateway

Comment: Are you sure that it is _only_ configured to use private subnets? Your description matches what would happen if it was configured to use a mixture of public and private subnets.